# Can I set a default picture for an object's picture field through a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I have a `car` object that currently has no default picture, and is causing issues when there isn't a user-uploaded picture.  I'd like to make a default picture, and was wondering if this would work:

```
class AddPictureToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cars, :picture, :string, default: assets/images/default.jpg
  end
end
```

The default part is what I would be adding, not sure if that path is correct within the migration either.

OR if I need to go into ImageMagick and **EDIT** Carrierwave's (previously said Paperclip's) settings for this to be more robust.  What should I do?

EDIT 
**Car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :year, presence:true, length: { maximum: 4 }
  validates :brand, presence:true
  validates :model, presence:true
  validates :vin, presence:true, length: { maximum: 17 }
  validates :mileage, presence:true
  validate  :picture_size

  private

    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

EDIT **picture_uploader.rb** with default_url suggestion

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [380, 240]

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("/images/default.jpg")
  end
end
```

Default picture located at assets/images/default.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid storing the fallback image path in the database, because that makes it much harder to change the default later on.

**Paperclip** allows default (fallback) images. Just add something like `default_url: "/images/default.jpg"` to your `has_attached_file` configuration.

See: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#models

If you use **CarrierWave** just add a `default_url` method to your Uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/default.jpg"
  end
end
```

See: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

If you use the **AssetPipeline** you will need to use the `asset_path` helper to build the fallback URL. Change this line `"/images/default.jpg"` to:

```
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("/images/default.jpg")
```

Comment: I don't have a `has_attached_file` configuration.  I added my Car model above where I believe that would go, the picture config is `mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader`.  Can I just add a `has_attached_file` line with the default image or can I do it through PictureUploader?

Comment: @VirgeAssault : I updated my answer. Seems like you are using CarrierWave and not paperclip.

Comment: Yeah CarrierWave my fault.  I added the `default_url` method (edited question to include it) and ran `rake assets:precompile` but the image still isn't showing up by default.  Any ideas on further steps?

Comment: @VirgeAssault : I updated my answer to fix your problem with the asset pipeline.

Comment: Replacing that line with what you suggested isn't working (added it above). There are no errors on the page or server output.  The server isn't showing the picture at all when the object is created because it's not a parameter when a picture isn't added by the user, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: What URL does the server render into the HTML? Under what URL is the default image available on the server?

Comment: It's just rendering a blank `<span class="pic">`.  Could any of this (Maybe rake precompile) Have messed up my JS?  It's acting weird, adding two car objects instead of one, and dropdowns in the header aren't working.  Seems like changes aren't doing anything.

Comment: When it does not even render an image tag, then it does not sound like a problem with CarrierWave to me. Hard to tell without knowing the html partials and the JavaScript involved.